# what will be the mean of a column if there are missing values in the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, data-science

Example Data

| ID | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | +212 |
| 2 | y | NaN |
| 3 | xy | NaN |

df is the name of the dataset
The code below gave the names of the columns with no missing values.

```
no_nulls = set(df.columns[df.isnull().mean()==0])
```

isnull() will convert the dataset into something like this

| ID | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| False | False | False |
| False | False | True |
| False | False | True |

Can some one explain how mean will work on non-integers?

I used this and it worked but i am curious about mean

```
no_nulls = set(df.columns[df.notnull().all()])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case, `.mean()` is processing a dataframe of boolean values with `True` and `False` values only.  In this case, `.mean()` treat `False` as `0` and `True` as `1`.  Hence, if you look at the result of `df.isnull().mean()`, you will see:

```
df.isnull().mean()

ID       0.000000
Name     0.000000
Phone    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

Here, as columns `ID` and `Name` have all `False` values, `.mean()` will treat all as zeros and get a mean of zero.  For column `Phone`, you have one `False` and 2 `True`, hence, the mean is equivalent to taking mean of 0, 1, 1, i.e. `0.666667`.

As a result, when you check for `df.isnull().mean()==0`, only the first 2 columns will be `True` and hence, you get `{'ID', 'Name'}` for the result of `no_nulls`.

Referring to the [official document of DataFrame.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), you will get some hint from the parameter `numeric_only=` and notice its default behavior with default setting:

> Parameters
>
> **numeric_only**   bool, *default None*
>
> **Include only float, int, boolean columns.**
> *If None, will attempt to use everything, then use only
> numeric data.*